# How can I find $dy/dx$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What does $dy/dx$ represent for these questions?

- $y = x^5$
- $y = x+5$
- $y = b$, $b$ is a constant

Am I supposed to divide the $y$ by $x$? So, $\frac{y}{x^5}$ and $\frac{y-5}{x}$? If so, what do I do with the third one? There is no $x$, only $b$.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking about derivatives or solving equations or neither?

Comment: No, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, formally a limit, i.e. $\frac{dy}{dx}(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{y(x+h)-y(h)}{h}$; it represents the instantaneous rate of change of a function at each point (if it exists). For many "nice functions", the derivative can be explicitly calculated, e.g. $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^4$ for the first one, $\frac{dy}{dx}=1$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ for the second and third one respectively.

Comment: Does this mean I should always reduce the power of x by one to "dy/dx"? The second one is 1 because of $x^0$? What becomes of the 5? Also, why is the third one 0?

Comment: Only if your function is a polynomial, as expressed in the answer below. It would be helpful if you learn some more about the motivation for doing derivatives, try the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=x^n$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=nx^{n-1}.$$

When you differentiate your three examples you get:

- $\frac{dy}{dx}=5x^4$
- $\frac{dy}{dx}=1$
- $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Check out [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derivative.html) link to learn more about differentiation.